# How to install OpenGL 4.0 or 4.5 for developing?

Tags: opengl

How i can install OpenGL 4.0 or 4.5 from terminal for developing in C++? I search about it but i can't find a source. And i do not have a directory named GL in **usr/include**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mesa is the GL library used. Ubuntu 16.04 includes Mesa 11.2 which supports OpenGL 4.1. Just install the `libgl1-mesa-dev` and `mesa-common-dev` packages to install the development files for it.

If you really need 4.5, you will likely need to develop against the propreitary AMD or NVidia drivers, and you will need a card which actually supports 4.5 to run any software you create using that version of the API.

Comment: I do installation,  but still i don't have GL directory in usr/include.

Comment: Sorry, I guess you also need mesa-common-dev.

Comment: I installed the above libraries but `glxinfo | grep -i opengl` still shows `OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0`. How do I develop in OpenGL4?

Comment: @Shashwat "core profile version string" tells you the OpenGL version currently supported by the Mesa drivers on your card. However, developing for OpenGL 4.x and having OpenGL 4.x support in your GPU are not the same thing. To _develop for_ OpenGL 4.x, you would just need to use new APIs that are only available in 4.x. This would then not run on hardware that doesn't support 4.x, but it is independent of development for hardware that does.

Comment: So, do you mean that after installing the above libraries, I can just use the new APIs to develop in OpenGL 4.x - whether it's supported or not? Secondly, I have `NVidia GeForce 920M` graphics card but still the vendor is shown to be `Intel Open Source Technology Center`. How can I change that and have support for OpenGL 4.x? Thank you!

Comment: I have those libraries but when I print the opengl version string in the code, it shows 3.0